# Foreign key relationship missing in ASP.NET MVC app using code-first approach with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building an ASP.NET MVC 5 "To Do List" app, where users can add categories and add tasks to categories. I am using Entity Framework 7 with a sort of "Code First" approach, but using an existing database.

I created a database in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio with a `Category` and an `Item` table, and each `Item` has a `CategoryId` column that is a foreign key to the Category's `Id` column.

Then I created an empty MVC5 app, with a database connection to this database. I created an `Item` class and a `Category` class in the *Models* folder that correspond to the tables in the database.

Item class:

```
namespace ToDoList.Models
{
    [Table("Item")]
    public partial class Item
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Category")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Category class:

```
namespace ToDoList.Models
{
    [Table("Category")]
    public partial class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            this.Items = new HashSet<Item>();
        }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want the view for an `Item` to display its `Category`'s `Name` property. The model for the view is a collection of all `Item`s in the `Item` table (`IEnumerable<ToDoList.Models.Item>`). Say I want to print a list with each item followed by the name of the category related to it. Here's the code that I have:

```
    <ul>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)</li>;

    }
    </ul>
```

The `Item` shows up just fine, but the page doesn't display anything for the `Category`. This same code actually worked when I used an ADO.NET Entity Data Model to create classes, but I'm not able to create an Entity Data Model using ASP.NET 5, so I'm trying out this code-first approach.

Any ideas on why the app isn't using the foreign key relationship or suggestions of what I can try?

Comment: Have you included `Category` when selecting Items?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: How do you selected your items? Have you tried `db.Items.Include("Category")`?

Comment: Where should I try adding that line? The action for the view in the controller looks like this: `public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Items.ToList());
        }`

Comment: use `db.Items.Include("Category").ToList()` as model instead of `db.Items.ToList()`

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Quick note, the argument is `Include(r => r.Category)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eager loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) to include the `Category` in the query, using:

```
var model = db.Items.Include("Category").ToList();
```

or

```
var model = db.Items.Include(x=>x.Category).ToList();
```

and then return the view: `return View(data);`